# display a message in a table cell

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a table where I display some values ​​in my cells. I can have empty cells, so I displays unavailability message in this case .

I would post my message in a different style as in the following screenshooot .
[image]

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bJvx7OQgWIjMci67fQQC?p=preview)

```
<p data-ng-class="{minPriceText: price.isMinPrice, priceText: !price.isMinPrice}" class="ng-binding minPriceText">38,00 €</p>
```

how to display my unavailability text across my cell as my example shows ..?

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Please try to clearly explain what your issue is

Comment: @WayneEllery how to display my unavailability text across my cell as my example shows ?

Comment: Sorry it's in a different language. Where does it say unavailable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS in your tag..

```
.yourClass {
     -moz-transform:    rotate(315deg);
     -o-transform:      rotate(315deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
     transform:         rotate(315deg);
      position: absolute;                    
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gw9tkLnzcCduI7Rx87ha?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could rotate your text.

```
.tablecell {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```